# React: Toggling two components between visible and invisible

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've looked about on stack overflow for an answer to this question but haven't come across one for this specific problem. I have a landing page on which there is a form. The form has a 'Sign in' or 'Sign up' option. What I want to do is that when 'Sign in' is clicked, the component containing the form for the 'sign up' content fades out and the component for the 'sign in' content fades in and vice-versa.
An example of the webpage can be seen below. So we have a toggle top right and the 'Sign In/Sign Up' titles above the form which I also want to perform this toggling of content on click.

[image]

[image]

Having looked into this I've found that react has a 'unidirectional flow' from parent to child, but still dont know how I'd implement this at all. The `PageSwitcher` is its own component, which when clicked needs to then somehow set the state of a variable such as `active` for `<SignUp />` and `<SignIn />` to change. Likewise the same needs to happen for when the `SignIn/SignUp` titles are clicked.

So I know I need to make use of state to determine which component to display and which one to hide. But the clicks to do so are being made on separate components. So I need to somehow route a call from a component such as the `<pageSwitcher />` to `<SignUp />`, which from what I've read you can't do in react?

Clearly I'm very new to this framework so must be misunderstanding some basic concepts, as this is a really fundamentally simple thing I'm trying to do. I could do this in an instant with just plain javascript instead, is this the better approach?

**CODE**
*App.js:*

```
function App() {
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <Landing_Aside />
            <Landing_FormSide />
        </div>
    );
}
```

*Landing_FormSide:*

```
class Landing_FormSide extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App__Form">
                <PageSwitcher />

                <div className="FormTitle">
                    <a href='#' className='FormTitle__Link'>Sign In</a>
                     or
                    <a href='#' className="FormTitle__Link FormTitle__Link--Active">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <SignUp />
                /* Havent included <SignIn /> here otherwise it'd be visible */
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

*SignIn/SignUp:*

```
class SignUp extends React.Component{
    state = {
        active: false
    }

    render(){
        return(
               ...content...
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the state in the parent component like this:

```
const SignIn = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <form>
            <input name="name" type="text"/>
            <input name="password" type="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const SignUp = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <form>
            <input name="name" type="text"/>
            <input name="last_name" type="text"/>
            <input name="password" type="password"/>
            <button type="submit">Sing up</button>
        </form>
    )
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = {
        visibleLogin: true
    }

    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.handleVisible = this.handleVisible.bind(this);
    }

    handleVisible( value ){
        this.setState({
            visibleLogin: value
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onclick={this.handleVisible(true)}>Sign in</button>
                <button onclick={this.handleVisible(false)}>Sign up</button>
                { visibleLogin?<SignIn/>
                :<SignUp/>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Otherwise you can use Redux for more complex states sequences managing.

Comment: Thanks, the this.handleVisible(true) threw an error, but after changing it to () => this.handleVisible(true), it worked nicely. One last thing however, if I now wanted to change the styling of say <PageSwitcher /> and other elements on the webpage when this button is clicked, how would I go about doing it? I'd need to somehow pass the <PageSwitcher /> component a value such as 'colour', change the css styling of the clas and rerender it?